# I am using openpyxl to create a conditional formatting rule. how do i remove this formatting via python?

Tags: python, openpyxl, conditional-formatting

I want to remove all conditional rules before applying the new formatting. How should I do it?

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
from openpyxl.styles import Color, PatternFill, Font
from openpyxl.formatting.rule import FormulaRule


table = load_workbook(filename = 'lab5.xlsx')
ws = table.active

redFill = PatternFill(start_color='FF2400',
                  end_color='FF2400')

itfont = Font(italic = True)

for sheet in table:
    if sheet.title == 'macro':
        ws.conditional_formatting.add('G4:Y7',
                                      FormulaRule(formula=['G4=1'], fill=redFill))

        ws.conditional_formatting.add('G4:Y7',
                                      FormulaRule(formula=['G4=0'], font = itfont))
    
table.save('lab5.xlsx')
```

Comment: Just reset `ws.conditional_formatting`

Comment: Say how can I do it, please

Answer (score 0):

In the library, the class `conditional_formatting` looks like this

```py
class ConditionalFormattingList(object):
    """Conditional formatting rules."""


    def __init__(self):
        self._cf_rules = OrderedDict()
        self.max_priority = 0
```

Just reset the values using the magick method

```py
ws.conditional_formatting.__init__()
```